# " SharePoint Online Client Components SDK " Versus " SharePoint Online Management Shell"

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-online, powershell, online

I am working on my first sharepoint online project. now when we work with sharepoint on-premise we use *SharePoint  Management shell* , to execute power-shell commands.

now on my sharepoint online 2013 , currently i need to run these 2 commands:-

1.To enable custom scripting

```
Set-SPOsite -DenyAddAndCustomizePages 0
```

and

2.To enable master page editting :-

```
# Paths to SDK. Please verify location on your computer. 
Add-Type -Path "c:\Program Files\Common Files\microsoft shared\Web Server Extensions\15\ISAPI\Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.dll"  
Add-Type -Path "c:\Program Files\Common Files\microsoft shared\Web Server Extensions\15\ISAPI\Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.Runtime.dll"  

# Insert the credentials and the name of the admin site 
$Username="admin@tenant.onmicrosoft.com" 
$AdminPassword=Read-Host -Prompt "Password" -AsSecureString 
$Url="https://tenant.sharepoint.com/sites/teamsitewithlibraries" 
$setting=$true
```

so i am not sure why tool i need to use "SharePoint Online Client Components SDK " OR " SharePoint Online Management Shell" ?? any why. or each script need separate  toolS ???

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need both. The management shell allows you to talk to SharePoint Online. The client components are necessary to bridge the gap in functionality between on prem powershell commands and cloud commandlet offerings. I just put together a post on setting up PowerShell for Office 365 usage.

The management shell has a limited subset of commands, so sometimes you can use a native command, but most often you need to you the client components to use CSOM in PowerShell. If you don't want to use PowerShell, you can build your own console apps using the CSOM framework.

http://ericjalexander.com/blog/2016/11/03/Setting-Up-PowerShell

Also, modifying the master page in SharePoint Online is highly discouraged. Altering it means you will be missing out on features as Microsoft rolls them out. There are other means to satisfy customization, like using the Alternate CSS properties to attach a custom CSS override or use themes to change the look, or using Custom Actions to do custom Javascript.

By customizing your master page, if Microsoft updates the command bar, or app launcher, or rolls out new UI components, you might not get them. You have to determine what has changed in their stock master page, then roll that into yours and then replicate that across your entire collection.

Comment: thanks for the reply.. first point what do you mean by "_The client components are necessary to bridge the gap between on prem and cloud commandlet offerings_"? second point can i know why it is discouraged to modify the master page? now let say i want to define a custom css or apply some changes to the layout,, then how i can do so? i mean when i work with on-premise sharepoint, i use to take a copy of the seatle.master master page, and do some modification to the new master page. and i have never face any problem..

Comment: although we have install many updates to sharepoint ,, or the situation with SP online is different ? at the end the original seatle.master will stay as is,, and incase we face any problem i can publish the original seatle.master as default master page again... does this sound valid ?

Comment: You need the client components to be able to create your own functions using CSOM, a few examples, there is not a Get-SPList or Get-SPWeb in the SharePoint Management Shell, you have to create that yourself. The PowerShell coverage between the cloud and on prem is night and day.

Comment: ok i thought you mean that i need the client components to bridge the gap between an existing SP on-premise.. so now my PC is on windows-7 .. and to be able to install both of them i need powershell 3.0 (currently i have powershell 1.0),, so to get powershell 3.0 i need to install  Windows Management Framework  ?? is this correct ? second point , now inside my PC i have sharepoint designer 2013 installed,, so generally speaking can installing; Windows Management Framework  & the SDK & the online managemnt shell affect the sharepoint designer ?

Comment: correct, framework, management shell, client components. It shouldnt have an affect on spd

Comment: so I will install these and try them,,, but referring back to my question so the 2 scripts i mentioned will be running under the  "_SharePoint Online Management Shell_” ,, but without the SDK the “_SharePoint Online Management Shell_” will not understand the commands ?is this correct ? i mean the SDK is just for including the required sharepoint dll files ,, but it is not used to run the actual 2 commands?is this correct ?

Comment: regarding your update for editing a master page.. now me as a developer i do understand the drawbacks of updating a master page.. but you know how customers are always hungry for layout customization... second point i have now my online site collection is of type Team site and its publishing infrastructure feature is disabled (and i am not planning to enable it at this stage).. so not sure how i can define a custom css for my seatle.master master page ,, is this possible.. so at this stage i can apply my modification to the  Alternate CSS .. but not sure how i can access it ?

Comment: seems you mistakenly remove the link to http://ericjalexander.com/blog/2016/11/03/Setting-Up-PowerShell on ur last edit it is very helpful ..